# Downloading a file with Knockout bindings, ASP.NET MVC stack and no Razor

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Trying to find a resource that could point me in the right direction for downloading a file with this particular stack. It's more challenging than it seems, especially since I'm unable to use Razor in accordance with house rules.

The code execution can get from the markup, to the knockout, and then the C#, but it doesn't start a download like I would expect in ordinary webforms non-MVC ASP.NET.

mark up:

```
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-2"><img data-bind="attr: {src: image}, click: $root.downloadFile/></div>
```

the knockout/javascript call:

```
self.downloadFile = function(e){
    if(e) {
        attachmentId = e.id;
        helpers.ajax.getJson(root, "/Files/DownloadFile/", {fileId: attachmentId }, function(x){
        attachmentId=0;
        getFiles();
        });
}
```

...
related javascript functions called here:

```
helpers.ajax.getJson = function(path, url, data, onSuccess, onError){
    helpers.ajax.async('GET', path, url, {
        data: data,
        cache: false,
        async: true,
        error: onError,
        success: onSuccess
    });
};

function getFiles(){
    self.files([]);
    helpers.ajax.getJson(root, "/Files/GetFiles",
    { profileId: self.ProfileId() },
    function (files) {
        if(files) {
        $.each(files, function (i, v) {
            self.files().push(new file(v.AttachmentId, v.FileTypeDescr, v.FileExtension, v.FileName, v.UploadedBy, v.UploadDate, v.CompletionDate));
        self.files.valuehasMutated();
        });
    }
});

}
```

C#

```
public FileResult DownloadFile(int fileId)
{
    ODSAPI.AttachmentFile file = FileFunctions.GetById(fileId); 
    if(file != null)
    {
        return File(file.FileData, file.ContentType);
    }
    return null;
}
```

this returns the correct file information and the bits from the database when I step through the code and view the file variable.

Comment: So... what happens on the javascript side? Also, while Razor wouldn't help here, it's kind of weird to say you are using MVC without Views

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The JSON call in the Javascript was incorrect as it called for a JSON object. Rather, it should have been:

```
window.open(root + "/Files/DownloadFile?fileId=" + attId, '_blank');
```

instead of helpers.ajax.getJson()

Answer (score 0):

you could use http://danml.com/download.html to download file from javascript AJAX return

for exmaple

```
     download(data, 'Export.csv', 'application/csv');
```

where data will be return from your ajax request and file name and file type.